# How to animate an image in canvas using requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I want to move an image from left to right using requestAnimationFrame in HTML5 canvas.

```
let canvas= document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
let c= canvas.getContext('2d');

let image= new Image();
image.src="./balloon.png";

let x=0;

function draw(){
    image.addEventListener("load",()=>{
        c.drawImage(image,x,0);
    });  
}

function update(){
    x+=1;
    draw();
}

function animate(){
    c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    update();  
}
animate();
```

Normally image is loading but as I try to add animation frame in it then the image disappears.

Comment: `load` only fires once. call `animate()` within the callback of `addEventListener` and change `draw` to just `c.drawImage(image,x,0);`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, Now it's working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the image only once.

```js
let canvas= document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
let c= canvas.getContext('2d');

let image= new Image();
image.src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg";

let x=0;

 image.addEventListener("load",()=>{
        c.drawImage(image,x,0);
    });  

function draw(){
 
        c.drawImage(image,x,0);
  
}

function update(){
    x+=1;
    draw();
}


function animate(){
    c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    update();  
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```